# android: How to set the limits of the pan in achartengine?

Tags: android, achartengine, pie-chart

i am using a pie chart from the charting Library Achartengine in my pie chart activity when the pan is enabled, the pie chart can be dragged till infinity, how can i limit its pan sort of margins.
How to actually restrict the dimensions in which its should be pan enabled.

Any help will be of utmost importance.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set pan limits for the XYCharts only. You cannot do that for pie charts.